# Parsing HTTP POST in PHP using REGEX?

Tags: php, regex

Before I ask this I just want to state I have no previous experience with regular expression but do have an idea what they do/can accomplish.

I have a HTTP POST coming into my script that will look something like this:

```
tagId = "123(COMMENT),456(COMMENT),6782(COMMENT)"
```

where the numbers will always be `tag_ids` and the `(COMMENT)` will just be comments for humans i.e. not needed by the script.

I need just the number values so my original plan was to explode the variable on the commas and then loop through each of the elements in that array and just find the substring up to the first '('. But that seems like a very clunky way of doing things.

I'm wondering if there is a way to use regex to parse out the numbers in a much cleaner fashion than my original thinking.

Any tips or just pointers to helpful documents would be great, because as I've said I have not once used them.

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: The PHP manual strongly recommends that, if it is possible to achieve an aim using standard string manipulation rather than regular expressions, then we should do so, because regex matching can be very slow. In this case simple use of the PHP strtok function will solve this problem. Call it in a loop, alternately looking for ` ( ` and ` , ` as the match characters. But do go ahead and learn regular expressions, they are very powerful :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working regex:

```
\(.*?\)(*SKIP)(?!)|\d+
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eI7rI4/1)

It will match all numbers outside of parentheses. It assumes you can't nest the parentheses.

It works by matching parentheses and their contents, and discarding them, or a number (which will then be outside).

Comment: Looking over the demo, this is exactly what I am looking for. I'll have to play with it in php a bit but this is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thank you!

Comment: @Lucas Trzesniewski `(*SKIP)` that was something new for me. so what does that actually acomplish?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R it tells the regex engine to prune the backtracking tree and attempt the next match from the position where `(*SKIP)` is encountered *if it backtracks into `(*SKIP)`*. Then `(?!)` (equivalent to `(*FAIL)`) causes an immediate backtrack. On backtrack, `(*SKIP)` prunes the backtracking tree and causes the whole match to fail, leaving the current position at the place in the text where `(*SKIP)` matched. More info on [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex

```
\b\d+\b
```

to match the numbers in the tagId

example matches http://regex101.com/r/xU9aN5/1

OR

```
(?<!\()\b\d+\b(?!\))
```

if comment can contain digits like eg `123(456),789(foo)`

Comment: what about `123(456),789(foo)` ?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski i have edite the answer to include that as well Thank you for pointig out

Comment: Hehe, here's some more difficulty: what about `123(foo 456 bar),789(foo)` ;-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski just thought of that :P

Answer (score 1):

You may turn it into a JSON string

```
$tagID = '123(COMMENT123),456(COMMENT456),6782(COMMENT6782)';
preg_match_all('/(\d+)\((.+?)\)/i', $tagID, $matches);
$result = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
    $toAdd = '{"tagID":' . $matches[1][$i] . ',"comment":"' . $matches[2][$i] . '"},';
    $result .= $toAdd;
}
$result = substr($result, 0, strlen($result) - 1);
$result = '[' . $result . ']';
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt:

```
/(\d+)(?:\([^)]*\))?(?:,|$)/g
```

It works exactly as you intended, assuming that comments can't be nested and that the format is always the same.

You can check here for a working version: http://regex101.com/r/rS9sE7/2

Thanks to @LucasTrzesniewsk for spotting a "mistake" I made.

Comment: Good job, it's easier to grasp than mine. Side note: in case you want the comments to be optional, add a `?` like that: `(\d+)(?:\([^)]*\))?(?:,|$)`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski CR*P. I had it in mind, but I forgot to implement. But good catch.

Comment: You're welcome. But it wasn't a mistake IMO, as OP doesn't say if these comments are optional or not.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski It was a personal mistake. I was going to implement that way but I completely forgot it :/

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't only 1 solution for a problem, I will present another answer.

This is, by far, the most simple regex you can use for this:

```
/(?:^|,)(\d+)/g
```

It will match the numbers right after the beginning of the string or right after a coma (the char `,`).

You can check it working here: http://regex101.com/r/jA5tC3/2